# Transformations of 2d geometric objects in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geometry

I'm trying to build an app that you can do Rotation, scale, stretch and translates a geometric shape like the image below in flutter, I know that  I should use matrix4 and I'm trying to use some packages like [matrix4_transform](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix4_transform) and [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) but I don't know how exactly the matrix4 values effect the shape's Scale,Rotate and Translate .if there is any documentation or explaine i would appreciate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having a 4x4 matrix to represent a 3D transformation may be a bit counterintuitive.
Theoretically speaking, this **4x4** matrix represents a linear transformation in **3d** projective space. Long story short, it's a kind of "mathematical hack" that allows to represent scale/rotation/shear **and** translation as a single matrix.
This greatly simplifies further calculations, as combining any two transformations is just multiplying 4x4 matrices.
If you're interested in more, you can easily find a lot of info online, since this approach is widely used in pretty much all of computer graphics.
[Brief introduction](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm).

But, you don't really need to know exactly how to build or calculate matrices for different transformations. Flutter's [`Matrix4`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4-class.html) class has all the utilities you need.

```dart
final matrix = Matrix4.identity()
  ..rotateZ(pi/4) // 90 degree, in radians! 
  ..translate(10, 10, 0)
  // combine as many transformations as you want

// ...

Transform(transform: matrix, ...);
```